# How do I make search only search in post content?

Tags: search

I want to have two search bars, one which works normally and one that searchs only in the post content but I can't even find the code of the search funtion to create the second.

Can I use a plugin to make my search function only search in post content? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This line in $wp_query might be of interest:

```
$where = apply_filters_ref_array('posts_where', array( $where, &$this ) );
```

You could probably use a filter to toss in an additional post_type = 'post'. Something like:

```
function search_where( $where, &$wp_query ) {
  if ( $wp_query->is_search ){
    where .= " AND post_type = 'post'";
  }
  return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'search_where', 10, 2);
```

Comment: I think he wanted to just search `post_content` as opposed to all the other fields WP does by default.

Comment: Yes I want to search only post_content, however it isn't doing it by default it's also checking titles. Are you sure it only checks the content by default? I'm sure it's not doing it in my page because my posts are 99% and just one word for content

Comment: What about the `posts_search` hook?

Comment: hai, easy la... find much better than my code..
Thank you.!!